Time to kill some tags!
We have a lot of leftover clutter from early beta, but what I notice primarily is the incredible number of unused tags. Can I get a few people to view the tag list and nominate a couple dozen unused tags here? Once we all agree on what should go, we'll burn 'em. Make sure to look at tags with only one question attached.


Tags not associated with any question are automatically destroyed at
  03:00 UTC every day.

A: "How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or “zombie”) tags?"
I believe most of the unused tags in the end of the tag list are actually just tag synonyms for existing tags. 

Thanks, Ambo! In that case, I'll just go ahead and de-tag some stuff. (I'll make sure to document it and post here, and I encourage others to do the same.)

I have some ideas lined up, but I want to make sure everyone agrees first.

Harry potter?

Hero Factory?

All these?

Tracked vehicle and tracks?

All these except patent and sensor?

I'd leave almost all of those - We should probably merge [tag:model-identification] into [tag:identification] although I think it was used for MOCs rather than official sets, the others may drop off over time (i.e. Brickowl has gone) but many of the others are related to specific themes or topics.
